# google script emails multiple people with each having a different atachment

Tags: email, google-sheets

I am really new to google script (never used before)and I think I am trying to run before i can walk

I need to be able to send and email to a list of people but each person will need a different attachment, I don't have a clue.

Any ideas on where i should look?

Comment: Where is the attachment located? Google Drive?

Comment: yep google drive

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good place to start.  It's a tutorial created by google.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails

Here's Google Apps Script Class MailApp documentation.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app

Another tutorial...
https://ctrlq.org/code/20118-mandrill-send-email-google

Hope that helps you get started.

In terms of structure on your spreadsheet, you will need a column list of email address and beside each email address so unique identification of the attachment that is to be sent.  You would then loop through each row of that sheet and send an email for each address.

Comment: thanks the problem i have is that each person needs a different attachment

Comment: I understand...the last paragraph sets up how you might solve that problem.   Doing what you want requires programming in Google Apps Script.  It might be worth your while to go through Google's tutorial and learn how to send 1 email with an attachment.  Then modify the script to email multiple people in a loop.  Then add the component of email multiple people each with their own attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below code to send multiple mails with different email id, subject, body and attachment. Hope this helps!

```
function sendEmail(){
  var openSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<<YOUR SPREADSHEET ID>>").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = openSpreadSheet.getRange(2,1,openSpreadSheet.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    MailApp.sendEmail({
     to:data[i][0],
     subject: data[i][1],
     htmlBody: data[i][2],
     attachments:[DriveApp.getFileById(data[i][3]).getBlob()]
    })
  }
}
```

This is how the spreadsheet is configured.

[image]